# Preparing data for tbl_summary: convert to numeric without losing label attribute

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, gtsummary

I have read in a CSV survey with over 500 variables (as characters). I used library(labelled) to assign variable labels and value labels for most of these variables. I then pass the result into tbl_summary.

See here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/larmarange/labelled/master/cheatsheet/labelled_cheatsheet.pdf

In order to assign variable labels and values I first labelled all the variables by passing in a list for each variable. Next, I added value labels for most variables using "set_value_labels". In order to add value labels for the variables, I had to make sure that every single variable was a character.

The problem: Once I have labelled all the variables and values of interest, I cannot seem to convert to numeric without dropping the label.

Here is a mild example of what I am trying.

Read in the CSV file as strings:

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% mutate_if(is.numeric,as.character)
```

Assign labels to some variables:

```
var_label(mtcars2) <- list(mpg = "Miles Per Gallon", cyl = "Cylinder", disp = "Displacement")
```

Assign value labels to some variables:In order for this to work, ALL the variable need to be character (hence why I read in the CSV as strings). If not, I get the error:
`` Error: Can't convert `labels` <character> to match type of `x` <double>. ``

```
mtcars3 <- mtcars2 %>% set_value_labels(cyl=c(`4`="four",`6`=six,`8`="eight")) %>% haven::as_factor(.)
```

have::factors(.) is supposed to retain the labels, but it does not (perhaps because I labelled using a different package? Perhaps because these are not STATA labels, but manually coded labels?)

```
mtcars4 <- mtcars3 %>% mutate(mpg = as.numeric(mpg))
```

Run tbl_summary on mtcars3 (all strings), this keeps all the labels, and their values (great!), but it does not provide the mean values for variables that I perceive as numeric.

```
 tbl_summary(mtcars3)
```

I convert one variable to numeric so that I can see the mean value, rather than categorical. But now, the label drops away from every variable that I converted to numeric.

`tbl_summary(mtcars4)`

**How do I convert some variables of mtcars3 into numeric without dropping the label attributes?**

The class of the actual data before I apply the haven::as.factor(.)

```
> class(survey_clean2$Q51_5)
[1] "haven_labelled" "vctrs_vctr"     "character"
```

Class  of data after I apply haven::factor(.)

```
class(survey_clean2$Q51_5)
[1] "factor"
```

---

**Here is an a better example with some data**

```
data_in <- read_table2("Q50_2     Q50_3  Q85 Q56
1    <NA>      <NA> <NA>
2    <NA>      <NA> <NA>
3    <NA>      <NA> <NA>
<NA>  Rarely Sometimes   12
5    <NA>      <NA> <NA>
6    <NA>      <NA> <NA>
7    <NA>      <NA> <NA>
8    <NA>      <NA> <NA>
9    <NA>      <NA> <NA>
10  Often Sometimes  65")
```

We have to convert it all to character because that is the actual format of my processed data.

```
data_in <- data_nonlab %>% mutate_all(as.character)
str(data_nonlab)
```

This does not work for numeric vars.

```
tbl_summary(data_in)
```

So I convert it to numeric.

```
data_in_num <- 
data_nonlab %>% mutate(Q50_2 = labelled::labelled(as.numeric(Q50_2), label = attr(Q50_2, "label")))

str(data_in_num)
```

But that var is omitted from the tbl_summary output, because:

```
tbl_summary(data_in_num)
Column(s) ‘Q50_2’ omitted from output.
Accepted classes are ‘character’, ‘factor’, ‘numeric’, ‘logical’, ‘integer’, or ‘difftime’.
```

Comment: @Daniel D. Sjoberg If you have any insight I would really appreciate it...

Comment: `as.numeric()` will drop the attributes (which labels are stored as). If you want to retain the labels you can use `mtcars3 %>%
  mutate(mpg = labelled::labelled(as.numeric(mpg), label = attr(mpg, "label")))` (or you could do it in batch). Or there may be a smoother way to do it. Is that what you were getting at?

Comment: @Andrew I tried your suggestion, I but I got this error: Column(s) ‘Q85’ omitted from output when I ran tbl_summary(data):" Accepted classes are ‘character’, ‘factor’, ‘numeric’, ‘logical’, ‘integer’, or ‘difftime’. I tried haven::as.factor(.) to convert it to a factor after coveting to numeric labelled, but then the numeric format gets changed and I see it as categorical.

Answer (score 3):

There is a fantastic function from the labelled package that helps in these scenarios: `copy_labels_from()`
https://larmarange.github.io/labelled/reference/copy_labels.html

You can use it to re-apply labels after they've been stripped by an operation.  See example below.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

# any operation that results in a loss of labels
trial2 <-
  trial %>%
  select(age, marker) %>%
  purrr::map_dfc(as.numeric)

trial2 %>%
  # copy the labels from the original data frame
  labelled::copy_labels_from(trial) %>%
  tbl_summary()
```

[image]

Here is a base R solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(
    cyl = factor(cyl, levels = c(4, 6, 8), labels = c("four", "six", "eight"))
  ) %>%
  labelled::set_variable_labels(mpg = "Miles Per Gallon", 
                                cyl = "Cylinder", 
                                disp = "Displacement") %>%
  select(mpg, cyl, disp) %>%
  tbl_summary()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I get this error when I try that..Error: `from` and `to` should be of same type

Comment: I wrote a small function that extracts the labels as a named list (http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/hotfun/reference/list_labels.html).  You can use this function to save the labels, and use the labelled pkg to re-apply them after they're lost.

Comment: I filed an issue to see if the labelled maintainer would be amenable to downgrading the type check from an error to a message

Comment: Thanks so much, I applied the labels a new a new object (called labels) and used copy_labels_from(labels) to apply the new labels, but I get this error: Error: `from` and `to` should be vectors

Comment: @NewBee can you update your question with what you tried, including your code and data or using the trial dataset?

Comment: I am not sure what you're doing with the labels object. It seems you're trying to work in the labelled world, but the labelled functions are not compatible with the way you're using them.  Rather than using that construct, I suggest you directly make the factors yourself and then apply the variable labels.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg I am not sure what you mean, I tried specifying the variable class before I apply labels, but labelled does not accept any other format except for character.  Do you mind expounding?

Comment: You're using haven and labelled together to create factor variables.  This is creating undo overhead and complexity, and is not the reason these packages exist.  I suggest you use base R to create your factors (use the factor() function), then apply the labels.

Comment: As a quick fix, you can keep your code above the same, but move the code that applies variable labels to AFTER the `as_factor()`.

Comment: @Daniel D. Sjoberg I tried that, but it doesn't produce sensible results. Each of the labels I added after defining the df as factor are interpreted as responses & the problem of numeric variables remain :(

Comment: I added a base R solution to my response